# Audio & Video files thumbnails files are missing

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, thumbnails

I can't see any thumbnails on my Audio & Video files (*works fine with the Pics though*)

I tried the Folder Options → Always show icons, never thumbnails. I've cleared the "*Thumbnails cache*" through CCleaner as well but nothing.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro.